# Using NCover free version

Tags: .net, ncover

I've downloaded NCover 1.5.8, run the .msi that's in the .zip file -- now what do I do? I can't find any documentation, I can't find any program to run.

Answer (score 1):

[NCover 1.5.8](http://www.ncover.com/download/community) is quite old and only supports .NET2 and below - AFAIK.

When you install it you will find a FAQ which tells yu how to use it and a console application under program files.

You may also find [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) and [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) of use. Both support .NET2 and .NET4 but [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) also supports 32 and 64 bit as well as sequence and branch coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation](http://docs.ncover.com/) in the "[Getting Started](http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/getting-started/)" article on the [NCover web site](http://www.ncover.com/).